# Deploy a Business Network Archive from online playground to IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-composer

Since I struggle to install the Hyperledger Fabric and Composer development environments locally on my Windows 10 machine I would like to know if it's possible to deploy a .bna file imported from the online Playground to the IBM Cloud or if I need the entire local installation.

I didn't find recent information about this but it appears that it was not possible on february 2017 but it may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a IBM bluemix account, you can follow this instruction: 
Deploying Hyperledger Composer Business Network to IBM Blockchain Platform Enterprise Plan on IBM Cloud. https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/platform-deployment/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I followed the instruction but I have a problem when using the composer network deploy : ✖ Installing runtime for business network undefined. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT. Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

a `.bna` file can only be deployed on a 'running' hyperledger-composer, may it be local or the online playground.

if you want to us it locally, [here are the complete installation steps(with prerequisites)](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html). 
after that, you can deploy your exported `.bna` file locally.
If you want to deploy it locally, then you have no option but to do all the above installations!

Hope this helps you!